# Material UI datepicker starts from 1900

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

Starting from 1900 when openTo is "year".

Version : @material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10"

```
<DatePicker
    disableFuture
    openTo="year"
    format="dd/MM/yyyy"
    label="Date of birth"
    views={["year", "month", "date"]}
    value={selectedDate}
    onChange={handleDateChange}
/>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in this sandbox? Also what issue are you having exactly? https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-williamson-kreg1?file=/src/App.js